# Как разделить строку на массив node.js?

Tags: массивы, node.js, строки

Работаю с ideone.
Не могу разделить строку-слово на массив из букв. 
Цикл for с использованием индекса не работает, и array.from() тоже.
У меня где-то ошибка, или в node.js это делается по-другому?

```js
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);

var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System['in']));
var line = reader.readLine();
line = Array.from(line);
System.out.println(line);
```

или так:

```js
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);

var reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System['in']));
var line = reader.readLine();
for(var i=0; i < line.length(); i++){
 System.out.println(line[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

разделить `line` на отдельные буквы

js

`line.split("")`

java

`line.toCharArray()`

Comment: Почему-то выводит это: [Ljava.lang.String;@1ef7fe8e

Comment: @ria это nodejs ?!

Comment: @entithat на всякий случай добавил вариант для java